# How does open data differ in quality depending on the source?

Tags: data.gov, best-practice, metadata

Let's talk about government data, e.g. data.gov, first. Putting aside "outliers," are most government data sets guided by e.g. "mandates" by the government? If not, how does the fact that say weather, vs. health data are put out by different departments affect difference in quality? Is British or German data quality likely to be either much better or worse than U.S. data?

As between open data from government versus private sources, does the quality of private sector data "converge" to best practices set either by the government or private parties? Or is it "all over the map?"

Data quality can be defined in many ways, but one that I am particularly interested in is metadata standards between various types of databases.

Comment: The actual question in your title has a fairly obvious answer. It would be unlikely in the extreme for all sources of open data to have the same quality, however that is defined. A better question would be *how* the quality varies rather than *if* the quality varies.

Comment: @JohnColeman: OK, adopted your suggestion. Thanks for your help.